# how can i use String... args? (String dot dot dot args)

Tags: java, string, args

> 12-01 15:54:01.509: E/JSON Parser(19280): Error parsing data
>
> org.json.JSONException: Value
>
> converted to JSONObject 12-01 15:54:01.514: W/dalvikvm(19280):
>
> threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417a22a0)
>
> 12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>
> AsyncTask #2 12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>
> doInBackground() 12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):     at
>
> android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) 12-01 15:54:01.519:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  at
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  at
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  at
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  at
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 12-01
>
> 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):    at
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>
> 12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  at
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>
> 12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  at
>
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 12-01 15:54:01.519:
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(19280): Caused by:
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 12-01
>
> 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):    at
>
> com.example.bubblewave0.Room_Main_Activity$IncreasePnum.doInBackground(Room_Main_Activity.java:264)
>   12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  at
>
> com.example.bubblewave0.Room_Main_Activity$IncreasePnum.doInBackground(Room_Main_Activity.java:1)
>   12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 12-01 15:54:01.519:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   12-01 15:54:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19280):  ... 4 more

How can i get value of array (string... args)?

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String temp = args[0];
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PNUM, temp));  // i get error over here
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
    "POST", params);               

    System.out.println(args[0]);  //this works well.... shows me 2.
}


Integer itmp = 2;
doInBackground(itmp.toString());
```

Comment: _"//getting error when i use temp for other things."_ What other things are you talking about. Show us

Comment: Check again if `System.out.println(args[0]);` really works

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: `12-01 15:54:01.509: E/JSON Parser(19280): Error parsing data` looks like it would be crashing on the `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest` call when the server returns invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your code throws an exception at

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PNUM, temp));
```

I dont think it can print the value again at

```
System.out.println(args[0]);
```

because execution would never reach there.

If for an execution of your code `System.out.println(args[0]);` works then `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PNUM, temp));` would surely work.

By the way you should null check args and also check its length before doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, your function `doInBackground(String... args) {` is almost (but not entirely) equivalent to `doInBackground(String[] args) {`. One practical difference is the former can also be called via `doInBackground();`. Regardless, this is how it works -

```
public static void test(String... args) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
}
```